# Optimize the query to dba_free_space

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

In my query for check the free space of data file, I need to join with `dba_free_space` but it was too slow.
I try to see what in dba_free_space: just 1200 records but need 11 mins to execute.
Some records like:

- `SYSAUX  3   526400  131072  16  3` (about 600 records)
- `UNDOTBS1    4   21248   1048576 128 4` (more than 110 records)
- `INDX    307 912336  393216  48  307` (about 50 records)
- ...........

Is it fragmentation? How can I optimize this `dba_free_space`'s query without damage the database.
I have try [this](https://blog.zeddba.com/2018/01/25/how-to-fix-queries-on-dba_free_space-that-are-slow/) but It's not working.

Comment: Do you have a lot of objects in the recycle bin ?

Comment: The user_recyclebin is empty and dba_recyclebin have about 263 records (all of them contains OPERATION 'drop')

Comment: all of them have same  `OPERATION` is DROP, `TS_NAME` is SYSAUX, `TYPE` is TABLE

Comment: Perhaps you could add your query and an explain plan?  You say "I have try", did it succeed?  Do you have PDBs? Nothing to do with performance: who's dropping tables from sysaux?

Comment: Even one table in the recycle bin leads to terrible paths being hit in the execution plans involving `dba_free_space`. Possibly the best option would be to say goodbye for good to the tables in there and do `purge dba_recyclebin;`

Comment: @GerardH.Pille "I have try", I mean I ran all guides successfully by that link but it is not helping me at all. Still 11mins when query `select * from dba_free_space`.

Comment: @AndrewSayer I know this kind of stupid question but I wonder "Can I find the true name of object from the object_name in dba_recyclebin? I just see it like `BIN$0dP2RpfLYMbgU3WMNgqEYg==$0` and `WRI$_RCS_432_2`"

Comment: Select original_name from dba_recyclebin where object_name = 'BIN$0dP2RpfLYMbgU3WMNgqEYg==$0'

Comment: Big thanks to both of you. You save my day. Once again, thank you.